# bsearch() comparing by name

Tags: c, function, struct, bsearch

I have a `struct employee` comparators and `main`:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 20
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int salary;
    int experience;
} employee_t;

void main()
{
    int i;

    employee_t** employeeArray = (employee_t**)malloc(sizeof(employee_t*)*5);
    employee_t nonExstingEmployee = {"v"};

    for(i=0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        employeeArray[i] = (employee_t*)malloc(sizeof(employee_t));  //alocate each employee
        readEmployee( employeeArray[i] ); 
    }

    puts("beforesort\n");

    for(i=0; i <2 ; i++)
    {
        printEmployee(employeeArray[i]);
    }

    puts("after salary sort\n");
    qsort(employeeArray, 2, sizeof(employee_t*), compareEmployeesBySalary);
    for(i=0; i < 2 ; i++)
        printEmployee( employeeArray[i] );

    if (bsearch(&nonExstingEmployee, employeeArray, MAX_SIZE, sizeof(employee_t), compareEmployeesByName) == 0)
        puts("employee found");
    else
        puts("no employee found");

}


    int compareEmployeesBySalary(const void* a, const void* b){
            employee_t* one = *(employee_t **)a;
            employee_t* two = *(employee_t **)b;

            if (one->salary == two->salary)
                return 0;
            else if (one->salary > two->salary)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
    }

    int compareEmployeesByName(const void* a,const void* b)
    {
        employee_t* one = *(employee_t**)a;
        employee_t* two = *(employee_t**)b;

        if(strcmp(&one->name, &two->name) == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I need to use `bsearch` comparing the names (with some employee that does not exist in the array), my `qsort` function works(comparing by salary)
no matter how I initialize the employee for `bsearch` it always says its not there (I'm trying to test this with existing employee first),

How should I initialise my employee (or what should I change?)

---

[update from comment:]

This is my `readEmployee()`:

```
void readEmployee(employee_t *emp)
{
  fflush(stdin);
  printf("Please enter Employee's name:(max 19 chars)");
  scanf("%s", emp->name);

  fflush(stdin);
  printf("Please enter Employee's salary:");
  scanf("%d", &(emp->salary));

  fflush(stdin);
  printf("Please enter Employee's experience:");
  scanf("%d", &(emp->experience));
}
```

I'm comparing the `nonExstingEmployee` (which exist in the array for testing) and my `employeeArray`.

Comment: For starters: This `if(strcmp(&one->name, &two->name) == 0)` does not look good, The compiler should have yelled a warning out you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I initialise my employee

You might want to show us how you do it (`readEmployee()`?), and we would comment on this.

> (or what should I change?)

Two issues:

1. The array to be searched is not `MAX_SIZE` long, but `2`.

   So this line

   ```
   if (bsearch(&nonExstingEmployee, employeeArray, MAX_SIZE, sizeof(employee_t), compareEmployeesByName) == 0)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if (bsearch(&nonExstingEmployee, employeeArray, 2, sizeof(employee_t), compareEmployeesByName) == 0)
   ```
2. In `compareEmployeesByName()` you pass the "wrong" address.

   This line

   ```
   if(strcmp(&one->name, &two->name) == 0)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if(strcmp(one->name, two->name) == 0)
   ```

Comment: this is my readEmployee:
`void readEmployee(employee_t *emp)
{
 fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter Employee's name:(max 19 chars)");
    scanf("%s", emp->name); 
 fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter Employee's salary:");
    scanf("%d", &(emp->salary)); 
 fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter Employee's experience:"); 
    scanf("%d", &(emp->experience));

}`
im comparing the nonExstingEmployee  (which exist in the array for testing) and my employeeArray

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple: you `qsort` by salary yet `bsearch` by name. It won't work.

`bsearch` performs binary search in *sorted array*. Not any sorted array but *an array sorted according to the search criteria*. You must either previously perform `qsort` by name or stick to `lsearch` (that is linear search which doesn't depend upon previous sorting).

Comment: Doh, yes, could catch! Totally missed this ... :}